# SilverStripe 3: Gallery Module 1.1, EditForm error - Trying to get property of a non object

Tags: php, module, gallery, silverstripe

Using SilverStripe 3.1.2 and [gallery module 1.1](https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery) I'm getting the following error when clicking "edit" on existing images.

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iframe_jQuery.find')"

If I upload a new image I get this error when trying to edit it:

[image]

I've tried dev/build and flushing numerous times. I did not have this issue with the previous version I was using but that version was not allowing me to upload the images. I'm stuck for ideas and trying to work out what needs to change and exactly what this means.

Comment: Did you install using composer? Or did you install manually and missed a dependency?

Comment: manually.. I can't see any dependencies on github that I'm missing. And it was working with the other version. So I'm not sure whats stopping it working.

Comment: educated guess: upload problem? Any chance to clear the gallery database on a dev machine? can the webserver write to the assets directory? double check the file perms!

Comment: while we're on upload problem: can you check the webserver error log and/or syslog if there is any hint for you? Could also be a too big file etc...

Comment: I can upload to all other upload areas of the site including assets. I can upload to the gallery. It just errors trying to edit the Caption clicking the edit button. The files are tiny like 50kb too. I could take a look at the database but don't want to remove other data associated to those gallery pages..

Comment: that's where i'd throw xdebug on it. I think you have some bogus database and one image object is not returned as it should, so the query for $joinObj returns null and $joinObj->Caption just fails. Try to debug this line, xdebug, var_dump(), echo... anything is fine if you get that error ;) Maybe it's a bug in that module and that code needs to be wrapped in an if statement?

Comment: I am able to recreate this issue.

To recreate this issue add a new image to a gallery page, click edit on the new image, click save on the image. 

An error occurs because the many to many instance between the gallery page and the image has not been saved to the database yet. This does not happen until the page is saved / published. Editing and saving the image tries to save the Caption variable, which is on the GalleryPage_Images table and which does not exist for this instance yet.

The page needs to be saved before the new images can be edited.

Comment: I have brought up this issue on the [module's git hub page](https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery/issues/10).